# Recursive struct in C

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct mystruct
{
    void (*ExitFnPtr)(mystruct);
    int a;
}mystruct;

int main()
{
    mystruct M;

    printf("Hello, World!\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Hi all, does anyone know how to solve the recursive struct error listed above?

Comment: Please add the error message to your question - we can't read your mind! ;-)

Comment: `void (*ExitFnPtr)(struct mystruct);`

Comment: Builds fine http://ideone.com/XQ6A2t

Comment: @imreal , With a warning:"*warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]*"

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing recursive with that.

Your problem is just that the definition of mystruct is not known until the end of the struct's definition.

Try

```
typedef struct mystruct
{
    void (*ExitFnPtr)(struct mystruct ms);
    int a;
} mystruct;
```

`struct mystruct` is the same as `mystruct` (you just typedef it), but known at that point in time.

You could also do a forward declaration if you don't want to change your original code (although it's not as readable as the above:

```
typedef struct mystruct mystruct;

typedef struct mystruct
{
    void (*ExitFnPtr)(mystruct ms);
    int a;
} mystruct;
```

Comment: Is the second `typedef` strictly necessary ?

Comment: No, you can leave it out, but it doesn't do any harm.